# How to power this servomotor?

Tags: servomotor, power

I would like to use and test [this type of servo motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-phase-NEMA-52-35N-m-4956ozf-in-Closed-loop-Stepper-servo-motor-driver-kit-JMC/32712846667.html?scm=1007.13339.33317.0&pvid=2578774e-484b-461c-9849-e602e6df8bac&tpp=1), significantly stronger than the ones I've been using previously.

However the datasheets seem to be limited and I can't exactly tell how to use the driver.

1. Would it be fair to assume that to use this system, I would get say a 500 W (or higher) power supply and be able to plug into my (North American) wall outlet to use this motor? And if so, would that give me enough power? I believe NA wall outlets give something like 12 A @110 V max, or 1.32 kW.
2. How could I tell if this is enough for the above servo, or might I have to upgrade to using an industrial power line?
3. What if I want to power multiple of these motors at the same time? Surely 1 power outlet wouldn't work.
4. [semi-related bonus question]  What is the difference between "2 phase", "3 phase" etc in this stepper/servo motor?

Comment: I'll caution you against buying this. At a minimum, if you're insistent on buying it, contact the vendor and get everything clear. I'll point out the typical eBay scam - you may not be buying *everything* in the picture. To be explicitly clear, the title says "motor **driver** kit*. It does NOT say "motor kit". For shipping to the US at least, the shipping cost is almost the cost of the part, and Return Policy rule 4 says, "Return shipping is to be paid by the buyer." So, you can return it for any reason within 14 days, but your net refund is the base $355 on nearly 842 spent.

Comment: Check the schematic on the page - the motor doesn't have a part number. Only the driver does. The post may be advertising what kind of motor *is compatible* with the driver they're selling. It's not clear. Again - ask everything in advance before you buy.

Comment: Absolutely, I was able to obtain a datasheet of the motor from the supplier with basic dimensions and torque/speed curves. It's risky but the reward is high too.

Comment: Also: I'm fairly certain it's motor + driver. Because the package weight is 21KG and motor weight is 19KG or so. Alibaba/express is very forgiving to foreign buyers with a history, I've been refunded before for products not received (including shipping fees).

Answer (score 2):

1. No. If there is no {installation, electrical, maintenance, etc} manual/description etc. (and maybe add also quality certificate also here) it is not fair to assume anything. Buying something without knowing its characteristics and placing it under current is a fire hazard, therefore it is not safe to assume characteristics! Guessing characteristics form picures is never a good idea.
2. From the (missing) installation manual.
3. If a motor consumes 500 W then 1 electrical outlet capable of supplying 1,32 kW can power 2 motors. 2 Electrical outlets capable of supplying 1,32 kW can power 2 each.
4. phases are the number of "inputs" for a motor. a 3 phase motor needs 3 signals to turn (dephased from each other) a two phase motor need two. The number of phases times the number of poles give the number of steps which divided 1 rotation (if I am not mistaking).

Comment: Ah alright so phases has to do with the default step angle it seems? Are there advantages of 2 vs. 3 phase systems other than that? And I'll try to follow up with datasheet information for the product.

Comment: 2 adjacent electrical outlets will likely be on the same 15A breaker circuit so the conclusion in point 3 may not be valid.